Extracting an element from any two-element set
To be able to retrieve a single element from the Kuratowski pair $p=(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ (where $a$ and $b$ can be any objects) e.g. the first one we can construct the following function $f$
$$f(p) = \bigcup\bigcap p = \bigcup \bigcap \bigg\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\bigg\} = \bigcup \big(\{a\} \cap \{a, b\}\big) =\bigcup \{a\} = a$$
Is it possible to construct a function $g$ in a similar way that for a simpler structure of a two-element set $d=\{a,b\}$ returns a single (any) element
$$g(d)=\ ? $$
Does the function $g$ (if it exists) require more ZF axioms than $f$?
Update 2024-07-31
It looks that function f(p) not exists in frame of ZFC - more detail here. However we can drop concept of function and talk about existence of "procedure" of extracting element from two element set (similar to "procedure" of extracting element from pair given above).

Yes, this requires some form of choice. For example, it implies countable choice over two-element sets $\mathsf{AC}_{\mathbb{N}, 2}$, which is not provable within ZF.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081822/can-i-construct-a-collection-of-pairs-of-socks

@NaïmFavier If what you wrote is true, this would mean that within ZF without Axiom of Choice, the reader cannot read elements of the set - and thus learn about new sets (e.g. printed in a book), because he would do something impossible/illegal. Therefore, adopting AC is a necessary condition to reading/learn new sets and operate on them.

You're confusing "picking an element from a given non empty set" and "uniformly and definably picking an element from every pair at the same time". Those are different things, just like that taking one step is different from walking a light-year.

@AsafKaragila In my question I did not mention anywhere about "uniformly and definably picking an element from every pair at the same time". Explain what you mean

I thought Asaf was replying to the OP. In any case, the question is ambiguous: since you mention Kuratowski pairs, which are a way of uniformly building pairs $(a, b)$ such that the first (resp. second) element can be uniformly extracted, I assumed that your question was about uniformly extracting an element from every two-element set. If you are asking about constructing a specific two-element set that one can't choose an element from, then see Anne's link. Either way, please edit to clarify your question.

@NaïmFavier: I was replying to the OP's comment, yes.

@KamilKiełczewski: You are asking for a function, definable or at least uniform, which takes an unordered pair and chooses an element, which would be defined on all unordered pairs. That is exactly what I had meant by my first comment.

@NaïmFavier The question was straightforward: about extracting an element from any two-element set (not about constructing such a set). That is, it is about explicitly specifying the function $g$ (just like the function $f$ for Kuratowski pairs).

@AndrésE.Caicedo "comment indicates incorrectly that some form of choice is required" - explain why. It seems that in order for a mind/device to read a two-element set, e.g. {7,3}, an extraction of each element must occur. If NaïmFavier is right, then it seems that some form of choice must be used (to choose which side to start reading from: from the left (7) or from the right (3)).

@AsafKaragila Yes. I'm asking about the function $g$ defined for each two-element set ${a,b}$ (just as the function $f$ is defined for each pair $(a,b)$). You wrote "You're confusing..." - are you saying that my question about the $g$ function is wrongly asked?

Suppose I know that $d$ is a set with two elements. The definition of "$d$ has two elements" is that there exist $x$ and $y$ such that:

$x\in d$ and $y\in d$,
$x\neq y$, and
for all $z\in d$, $z = x$ or $z = y$.

Great, so I know that there exist such $x$ and $y$, and I can go on with my proof working with $x$ and $y$, the two elements of $d$.
The above is just how first-order logic works, and it's perfectly sufficient for proving things in set theory.
Now the way you've phrased your question is a bit confusing, but it seems you're asking for something stronger. You want a (definable) function $g$ with the property that for any set $d$, if $d$ has two elements, then $g(d)\in d$. Have I interpreted your question correctly?
(Assuming ZF is consistent) we cannot prove the existence of such a function in ZF since, as Naïm Favier wrote in the comments, the existence of such a function would imply the axiom of choice for families of sets with sets with two elements, which is known to be independent of ZF.
Now in the comments, you wrote "within ZF without Axiom of Choice, the reader cannot read elements of the set - and thus learn about new sets (e.g. printed in a book), because he would do something impossible/illegal". This is misguided. ZF has no problem at all "reading" and working with the elements of a set, using the argument at the top of my answer.

Maybe "function" is too big a word - let's stop using it. I meant a "procedure" in general - it's best to do it for a specific example. For a Kuratowski pair, e.g. p=(7,3), the procedure for extracting e.g. the first element is simple $\bigcup\bigcap p = \bigcup\bigcap {{7},{7,3}} = \bigcup {7} = 7$ (similarly, although more complicated, the second element of the pair can be extracted). What does the "procedure" for extracting elements from the set ${7, 3}$ look like?

@KamilKiełczewski The elements of ${7,3}$ are $7$ and $3$. There, I've "extracted" them. This comment may sound flippant, but I'm totally serious about it.

I have some doubts because in your answer (not comment) you wrote: $x\in d$ and $y\in d$. But to write $7\in {7,3}$ you had to know it a priori - i.e. you had to first extract "7" mentally to be able to write this step i.e. $7\in {7,3}$ of your procedure... So in order to explicitly extract element 7, you first implicitly mentally extracted 7.

@KamilKiełczewski Repeating what I wrote in my answer: if I know a set has two elements, even if I know nothing else about it, I know that there is some way of labeling its elements as $x$ and $y$ (in fact, there are exactly two distinct ways to do this!). Once I have names for the elements, I can "use" them.

You wrote in last comment: "Once I have names for the elements, I can "use" them"  - ok so instead of $7 \in {7,3}$ you have $x \in {7,3}$ and $y \in {7,3}$. You know that $x\neq y$ and that for all $ z\in {7,3}, z=x$ or $z=y$. Now explain to me - how will you determine that e.g. x=7 or x=3? How will you extract a specific value from a name $x$?

Can you phrase your question in the precise language of ZF set theory? Otherwise it is difficult to guess what you mean.

@KamilKiełczewski In logic, there is no such thing as "extracting a specific value from a variable". It seems to me that you're trying to approach this from a "programming" mindset, which doesn't match up with how mathematics actually works.

If I assume nothing about $d$ other than that it contains two elements, then there's just nothing to be said about the values of its elements. If I know more, then I can use more. If I know that $7$ and $3$ are the elements, then I know everything - there's nothing to "extract". If I know the elements are natural numbers, I can take $x$ to be the smaller of the two and $y$ to be the greater. But (in ZF) there's no "procedure" which will unambiguously specify an element of an arbitrary two-element set.

I’ll take a crack at answering this by, in part, consolidating some of the comments that have been made already.
With regard to picking an element from a two-element set in a well-determined way, the crux of the issue seems to be whether we have any constraints on (knowledge about) what the elements are.

With sufficient knowledge, such as “the elements are real numbers” or “the elements are von Neumann ordinals” or “the elements are $\pi$ and $\{-2.8, e\}$”, then we can of course come up with a method of picking that works for any two-element set conforming to the assumed constraints (example: for a set of von Neumann ordinals, I can always just pick the least element)
But in a model of set theory where the Axiom of Choice is false, there’s no single “formula” or “procedure” that works to pick one element in a well-determined way from any arbitrary two-element set.

Naturally, if we take as given that the variable $a$ refers to one element of the set and the variable $b$ refers to the other element, then of course we can meaningfully speak of “the element $a$” and “the element $b$”. But neither of those expressions is necessarily the same thing as “picking” an element. To illustrate by an analogy with real analysis: If $I$ is some bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and I say “consider a point $p$ in $I$”, that doesn’t mean I’ve “picked” a point. To “pick” a point means saying something like “let $p$ be the mid-point of $I$”
